# No "Delivery Platform" feature in Manage page for my content hub instance

Tags: content-delivery, content-hub

I am not able to see `Delivery Platform` on the Manage page of my `Sitecore ConentHub 4.0` instance. Why it is missing? I have the superuser account and should be able to see this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into multiple options to resolve this but could not able to find anything related to it. Finally, I was able to resolve it by enabling a publishing setting from Settings under the Manage page.

To enable publishing or disable publishing to the delivery platform:

1. On the menu bar, click Manage.
2. On the Manage page, click Settings.
3. On the Settings page, in the Search field, enter Publishing and then click PublishingSettings.
4. On the PublishingSettings page:

   a) to enable publishing, click the publishing_enabled check box to select it.

   b) to disable publishing, clear the publishing_enabled check box.

[image]